# What does ?. mean in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, response, react-typescript

`const faq=data?.resources?.['FAQs'];`

What does this statement mean in **Typescript?**

I think it means if data has resources and FAQs in resources then faq will have value else null or false?

Comment: The same thing as in javascript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining